# Can I check if a page is inside a facebook tab somehow?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a webpage that is sometimes accessed from a facebook pagetab(not a facebook app), and sometimes it's accessed from a webpage as normal.

I know facebook sends a bunch of data to the app through the FB-object, that I already use for some other info, like scrolling. Is there any way to find out if the page is inside an facebook pagetab or not? It's an iframe, so I can't just check the url.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way of doing this is that you need to check for the presence of the signed-request. This is a POST variable which Facebook sends to your server and unfortunately, it cannot be read by JavaScript. For information about reading data from the signed request, check out [this Facebook help page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games/). If you do not want to register an app or decode the data, you can just check that `$_POST['signed_request']` is set.

However, upon further investigation, it looks like there is a way that we can test if we are on a Canvas/Page-tab in JavaScript. The FB JS SDK has a function called `FB.Canvas.getPageInfo`. If you are in a Canvas or a Page-tab then this function will call the callback you provide; if you are outside of Facebook, the callback will not be triggered:

```
 $('#pageInfo').click(function() {

  var displayType = 'external';

  FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function(response) {
    displayType = 'canvas/page-tab';
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('we are running ' + displayType);
  }, 1000);

});
```

The callback is asynchronous, so you'll have to adapt to that. Also, I don't think there is a way to detect the difference between a Page-tab or Canvas. You can look at the properties in the response to getPageInfo, but I don't think there is anything there which is unique to a Canvas/Page-tab.

Of course, another method would be to just add an extra parameter to the URLs of your Canvas and Page-tab and then read those:

[image] [image]

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
  return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
}

console.log(getURLParameter('type'));
```